# Creating a formula to update one row while disappearing in another

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I'm not an experienced Excel user for MAC. I'm running OS X El Capitan on my machine.

I have 2 columns:
1) contains the total sum of inventory items
2) # of items that's being purchased at the time the filler is filling the order

Is there a way for the values in Column 2 to disappear after the number has been entered but for Column 1 to still reflect the number of inventory items that have been pulled from the shelf? So when the next puller opens the excel report, they can also input a number into Column 2 and it will subtract from Column 1 again? Column 2 should be empty so that each time someone inputs a number it subtracts from the total sum of the inventory items

Comment: The only way to make text actually disappear (not just hide it via a color change) is with VBA.  I'd recommend a different approach to storing your "total sum of inventory items".  Think of each row in XL more like a pull-order, and then have a separate location (at the very top of that sheet, or in another sheet) that calculates how many items are left in inventory, based upon the starting point and all the pull-order (in the XL rows).

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional formatting to make the font color the same as the background.

$column2 > 0

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html